# Volume enclosed by shell structures in abaqus?

Tags: abaqus

This question is directly related to the tutorial at: https://learnsharewithdp.wordpress.com/2017/09/11/cube-on-pillow-fem/

- How do I calculate volume enclosed by a closed thin shell using finite element methods?
- Does abaqus or/and ansys or/and any other FEA software does it automatically?
- Particularly, abaqus supports python.
- Is there any python script or package which can be used with Abaqus 6.13 to this task?

Please don't confuse it with 3D solids. This one is hollow closed shell structure. For example, water bottles are closed thin shell structures. I need to calculate the volume without converting it in solid model.

This question is also cross-posted to Quora: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-calculate-the-volume-enclosed-by-a-close-thin-shell-using-finite-element-methods-Does-the-Abaqus-ANSYS-or-any-other-FEA-software-do-it-automatically

Comment: contrary to what you seem to believe, StackOverflow isn't a free code writing service. You're expected to show some effort in the form of inputs, required output, code, current output and exact error msgs ("It's not working", isn't an error msg ;-) ). Update you Q to show your best effort to solve your problem and people may try to help you. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Good Luck.

Comment: AND StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,    http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your sincere help and suggestion. I tried and after then I asked here (obviously I didn't got answer on quoro). It's fine if you/stackoverflow don't answer/help for free. I haven't demanded but tried to say that if you can't answer, don't believe that no body can't answer. So if if this question is not deleted, somebody out there might help me.

Comment: you need to use the 3d shoelace formula https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26015/2079